# Is my gparted partition editor looking okey?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, gparted

So. I re-installed ubuntu and there were some things that shoud have been preinstalled but are not. One of them was Gparted. Here is a screenshot of my gparted. Is it okey, I'm in a bit of doubt.

[image]

Comment: gparted is not pre-installed with Ubuntu even if it is included in the live DVD.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is OK. You have two partitions:

- linux main partition (root) which is `/dev/sda1` formatted as `ext4` and mounted as `/`.
- the swap partition `/dev/sda5`.

However because both the operating system and your files will be on the same partition, you'll lose all your data when you reinstall the OS. That's why is recommended to have a second partition mounted as `/home`.

Comment: That's okey, I want that